# finding the two surrounding elements in a list when click inside the container of a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

Suppose I have a container containing a list of items, so the markup looks something like

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-item" id="item-1"> ....</div>
  <div class="list-item" id="item-3"> ....</div>
  <div class="list-item" id="item-2"> ....</div>
  <div class="list-item" id="item-6"> ....</div>
</div>
```

Suppose the container and the items have reasonable spacing, so it is possible to click in the space between two items. What I want is to capture that click and then insert a new, editable list-item where the user clicked. To be able to insert a new list-item, I will need to know either the item to insert after, or before.

I am able to catch that click on the `container` class. But then ...

I would like to get the position from the click, and most importantly: I would like to get the closest (surrounding) `list-item`s so I can insert a new `list-item`.

Does anybody have any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With presuming that the list is vertical and the elements are positioned in the order they appear, you can use the event click position to compare to the element positions on the page, and add the list item accordingly, something like this:

```
$(".container").click(function(e){
    $(this).find(".list-item").each(function(el){

        if ($(this).offset().top > e.pageY) {

          // insert after this
            $('<div />').addClass('list-item').text('...').insertBefore(this);

          return false;
        }
    });

});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/qjcvf/

In case the list is horizontal, you would use the X offset instead, but if it is both vertical and horizontal, it will make the task somewhat more difficult.

Another approach is to add hidden elements in-between the list items, which you could use as triggers when the user clicks them, to know exactly where the element is positioned in relation to the list items.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the same approach as Niklas, although adding the following:

- Check to see if the container is the direct target of the click, to prevent clicks on the `<li>`'s themselves from adding new items.
- Use [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to add the new item.

Something like this:

```
$(".container").click(function(e) {
    var container = $(this);

    if (container.is(e.target)) {

        container.find(".list-item").each(function(index, element) {
            var el = $(element);

            if (el.offset().top > e.pageY) {
                el.clone().text('...').insertBefore(element);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/t43y2/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the padding on the objects (this is for horizontal items)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5kUWp/26/

JS:

```
$('div.list-item').live('click',function(e){
  var diff=e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  if(diff>$(this).width()) {
   var div = $('<div />');
   div.addClass('list-item');
   div.html($(this).text()+'....');
   div.attr('id','item-new');
   $(this).after(div);
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
div.list-item {
    padding-right:14px;
    margin:4px;
    float:left;
    border-right:1px dotted #444;
}
```